# Forcing a shell and flags on gnu make under git-for-windows

Tags: gnu-make

I'm running gnu make under a smaller distro of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), called [git-for-windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). I was expecting gnu make to behave like it does on unix. But I can't change `SHELL` from the default.

[GNU make have tons of hacks to try to work on MS-DOS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-a-Shell-in-DOS-and-Windows). I tried satisfying them all! still getting the default shell.

```
$ make -d
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
find_and_set_shell path search set default_shell = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
...
```

I created a simple Makefile with

```
SHELL := /usr/bin/bash

info:
    $(info path is $(PATH))
    $(info shell is $(SHELL))
```

and never mind that `bash.exe` do exists in my path, i still get the default. I tried to place bash.exe in the same place as the default sh.exe, and still get the default sh.exe. I tried following the unix path translation suggestions on their docs.

Only thing that works is a direct path (e.g. `SHELL := C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe`), or a msys path (`/c/Program Files/...`)

But then, it still ignores my `.SHELLFLAGS` options. Which i normally do not use on unix. I simply set `export SHELL = /bin/bash -xe` on my Makefiles)

```
$ cat Makefile
export SHELL = C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe
.SHELLFLAGS = --help
something:
    missingcommand

$ make something
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: missingcommand: command not found
```

(at least now i properly get bash)

Is there any way to override all the MS-DOS hacks on gnu make and just force my shell (ironically, if gnumake just accepted `SHELL=/bin/bash -xec` it would work on MSYS2/git-for-windows)

Or, how am I expected to set SHELL and SHELLFLAGS on this setup? ...and hopefully still being able to use the same source on unix.

Comment: As you discovered, you can't just plop a path like `/usr/bin/bash` into `SHELL` and expect make to go figure out what that path really means on the filesystem.  You have to provide the full path.  As for the second problem, it's because you are using an ancient version of GNU make (3.81, released in April 2006) and the `.SHELLFLAGS` variable was not available until GNU make 3.82.  You will have to upgrade to a newer version of GNU make if you want to use `.SHELLFLAGS`.

Comment: @MadScientist Would something like `make SHELL="$(cygpath -m /usr/bin/bash)"` work?

Comment: First, I don't really do Windows.  Second, the OP says they're using Git for Windows, which is based on MinGW (I think) so it's unlikely they have the `cygpath` program which (I think) is part of cygwin.  But certainly if that command returns the right path, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, just sumarizing the information in case anyone needs the full answer (probably me in the future)

git-for-windows contains a very limited version of msys/mingw32, which just enough to run git.

If you need more tools, you can install msys2 first, which is complete and even have a package manager, and then install the git-for-windows package in it. That is documented at https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Install-inside-MSYS2-proper